# Spring integration SFTP location file transfer error size 0 bytes

Tags: spring-integration

Can you help resolve below while writing file to `SFTP` location we are getting below error and file also showing `filename.xml.writing` size is 0 bytes

We are using `spring integration` version is 2.0.2

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to 
transfer file [/tmp/itemMaintenance_ef2a949b-e628-46a0-8dcc-
2067c5e3e8c0.xml.tmp] from local working directory to remote FTP directory.
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandl
er.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on DEBUG logging for spring framework as well as [for jsch as shown in the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-jsch-logging) to get more information about the failure.